# Trying to make Flexbox container of cards, flexItem 1 contains the cards but tests still not passing that they are being created

Tags: html, flexbox, visual-web-developer

```css
main{
  flex:1;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-bodyContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  height: inherit;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.flex-container { 
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
}
.flex-item{
  padding: 1em;
}

.flex-item#0{
  flex-basis: 240px;
}

.flex-item#1{
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: fill;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.flex-item#1, .flex-ImageContainer{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item#1 .flex-ImageContainer .flex-imageItem{
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background-color: white;
  margin:0.5rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1 3px;
}

.flex-item#1 .flex-ImageContainer .flex-item .flex-imageItem p{
  padding:0.5rem 1rem;
}

.flex-item#2{
  flex-basis: 180px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Cards</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">    
    <!-- normalize.css for cross-browser stuff -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="flex-bodyContainer">
    <main>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <section class="flex-item" id="0">
                <h1>Cards</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, ullam! Provident at accusantium, explicabo odio laborum ducimus earum amet repudiandae commodi quod distinctio, iste reprehenderit nihil ullam dolorum illo fugit.</p>
            </section>

            <section class="flex-item" id="1">
                <div class="flex-ImageContainer">
                
                    <div class="flex-imageItem">
                        <!-- Card 1 -->
                        <img src="img/abstract1.jpg" alt="abstract art">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, laborum.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-imageItem">
                        <!-- Card 2 -->
                        <img src="img/abstract2.jpg" alt="abstract art">
                        <p>Doloremque commodi unde eaque! Et natus dolorum corrupti ut numquam.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-imageItem">
                        <!-- Card 3 -->
                        <img src="img/abstract3.jpg" alt="abstract art">
                        <p>Odio praesentium cum nemo nesciunt architecto, quam voluptate porro inventore.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-imageItem"></div>
                        <!-- Card 4 -->
                        <img src="img/abstract4.jpg" alt="abstract art">
                        <p>Dignissimos consequuntur maxime harum debitis ratione, culpa iure pariatur quaerat?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-imageItem">
                        <!-- Card 5 -->
                        <img src="img/abstract5.jpg" alt="abstract art">
                        <p>Odit id earum commodi tempora voluptatum mollitia dolorum, perspiciatis nulla!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="flex-item" id="2">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
                    <li>Delectus, aliquid vitae?</li>
                    <li>Vero, molestias debitis.</li>
                    <li>Obcaecati, vitae amet?</li>
                    <li>A, nulla dolore!</li>
                    <li>Error, nesciunt at.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quo voluptates sint laudantium quaerat commodi!</p>
                <p>Aliquam, harum cumque aspernatur consectetur tempore dicta explicabo facere, adipisci sunt quas perferendis repudiandae sequi!</p>
                <p>Dolore aut error distinctio! Nemo impedit ipsum sunt neque vel enim unde incidunt nam consequuntur!</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
> <meta charset="UTF-8">  
> <title>Cards</title>
> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">    
> <!-- normalize.css for cross-browser stuff -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> </head>
> ```
>
> ## Cards
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, ullam! Provident at accusantium, explicabo odio laborum
> ducimus earum amet repudiandae commodi quod distinctio, iste
> reprehenderit nihil ullam dolorum illo fugit.
>
> ```
>         <section class="flex-item" id="1">
>             <div class="flex-ImageContainer">
>             
>                 <div class="flex-imageItem">
>                     <!-- Card 1 -->
>                     <img src="img/abstract1.jpg" alt="abstract art">
>                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, laborum.</p>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <div class="flex-imageItem">
>                     <!-- Card 2 -->
>                     <img src="img/abstract2.jpg" alt="abstract art">
>                     <p>Doloremque commodi unde eaque! Et natus dolorum corrupti ut numquam.</p>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <div class="flex-imageItem">
>                     <!-- Card 3 -->
>                     <img src="img/abstract3.jpg" alt="abstract art">
>                     <p>Odio praesentium cum nemo nesciunt architecto, quam voluptate porro inventore.</p>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <div class="flex-imageItem"></div>
>                     <!-- Card 4 -->
>                     <img src="img/abstract4.jpg" alt="abstract art">
>                     <p>Dignissimos consequuntur maxime harum debitis ratione, culpa iure pariatur quaerat?</p>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <div class="flex-imageItem">
>                     <!-- Card 5 -->
>                     <img src="img/abstract5.jpg" alt="abstract art">
>                     <p>Odit id earum commodi tempora voluptatum mollitia dolorum, perspiciatis nulla!</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </section>
>
>         <section class="flex-item" id="2">
>             <ul>
>                 <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
>                 <li>Delectus, aliquid vitae?</li>
>                 <li>Vero, molestias debitis.</li>
>                 <li>Obcaecati, vitae amet?</li>
>                 <li>A, nulla dolore!</li>
>                 <li>Error, nesciunt at.</li>
>             </ul>
>             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quo voluptates sint laudantium quaerat commodi!</p>
>             <p>Aliquam, harum cumque aspernatur consectetur tempore dicta explicabo facere, adipisci sunt quas perferendis
> ```
>
> repudiandae sequi!
>
> Dolore aut error distinctio! Nemo impedit ipsum sunt neque vel enim unde incidunt nam consequuntur!

Comment: Can you rephrase the question or elaborate? I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.